# Cast from 'Int?' to unrelated type 'NSNumber' always fails

Tags: ios, swift, casting

When I try to do the line below, I dont get a warning (not an error). What is this am I am doing something bad?

I am trying to cast the integer `earningsSoFar` to a NSNumber because I want to get the `.stringValue` out of it.

I want to understand what is the warning mean here and how to do this right.

`self.tv_salaryNumber.text = (earningsSoFar as! NSNumber).stringValue`

[image]

Comment: What you want to do? Cast Int to String or vice versa?

Comment: How is `earningsSoFar` declared?

Comment: earningsSoFar?.description ?? "" would work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can cast `Int` to `NSNumber` in this way

```
let a:Int? = 10
let b = a! as NSNumber
```

[image]

So,in your code,just try

```
self.tv_salaryNumber.text = (earningsSoFar! as NSNumber).stringValue
```

Also,as **zeneak** said,you can make it easier in his way